# Is there a word to summarize Intro and Outro videos?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use one word to call both type of videos, the *introductory video*, and the *outro video*.

In Spanish jargon sometimes I heard call it like "*cortinillas*", little window curtain.

Is there a similar word in English?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Please capitalize Spanish and English. The two words refer to completely different things. Therefore, one word cannot refer to both. Are doors and windows on a house the same thing?

Comment: "Outro" isn't in common use. How do you use the term? Do you mean something like a debriefing video, or a summary video, or a farewell video, or a concluding video, or something else?

Answer (score 7):

"Bookend" is the closest thing I can think of.

- Your introductory and outro videos are *bookends* to your primary video.
- The main video is *bookended* by the introduction and outro videos.
- My main video is done. Now all I need to do is add the *bookends* and the project will be complete.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bookend

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **brackets**

> The **brackets** of the Bavarian version are more elaborated than
> those of the original. The **opening bracket** features a sequence of
> title images... The **closing bracket** features a farewell to the camera
> and a list of end credits. [Nikolas Coupland; *The Handbook of Language and Globalization*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Handbook_of_Language_and_Globalizati/g8vbLTzxHpkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=intro%20outro%20video%20brackets&pg=PT313&printsec=frontcover)

> Often called credit music if it occurs at the end of the film, intro
> and outro music **brackets** the film. [Peter Rothbart; *The Synergy of
> Film and Music*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Synergy_of_Film_and_Music/Bptmdo5anEYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bracket%20intro%20outro&pg=PR16&printsec=frontcover)

> One traditional method of editing connects shots into a sequence with
> straight cuts and then **brackets** the sequences themselves with
> *fades* and *dissolves*. [S. Ascher and E. Pincus; *The Filmmaker's Hanbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JBKTF9PdgFMC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT525&dq=shots%20into%20a%20sequence%20with%20straight%20cuts%20and%20then%20brackets&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=shots%20into%20a%20sequence%20with%20straight%20cuts%20and%20then%20brackets&f=false)

> The flashback hypothesis is strengthened by the presence of Tak's
> voiceover narration in the opening scene, which we may assume to
> **bracket** the 1963 scene as well as the futuristic action. [Warren Buckland; *Puzzle Films*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Puzzle_Films/uV_uY-iliwgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=opening%20bracket%20intro%20film&pg=PA169&printsec=frontcover)